# Filling values in dataframe between 2 specific unique values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a following dataframe:

| index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | None |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | B |
| 7 | None |
| 8 | A |
| 9 | A |
| 10 | B |

The idea is to fill None in between A and B such that there is no consecutive A or B in the column.

Desired output

| index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | None |
| 4 | None |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | None |
| 7 | None |
| 8 | A |
| 9 | None |
| 10 | B |

This can be done easily with a loop but since I am using pandas and numpy, I hope to avoid the loop approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to propagate the non-None forward, then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), only keep the values that are not identical to this new series with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].ffill().shift()), 'Value'] = None
```

Or with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].mask(df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].ffill().shift()), None)
```

Output:

```
   index Value
0      1  None
1      2     A
2      3  None
3      4  None
4      5     B
5      6  None
6      7  None
7      8     A
8      9  None
9     10     B
```

Intermediates:

```
   index Value ffill shift     eq
0      1  None  None  None   True
1      2     A     A  None  False
2      3  None     A     A  False
3      4     A     A     A   True
4      5     B     B     A  False
5      6     B     B     B   True
6      7  None     B     B  False
7      8     A     A     B  False
8      9     A     A     A   True
9     10     B     B     A  False
```